# Bigquery query returning "pagetoken missing" - query works on other tables

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have my bigquery tables split up by day - each table as that day's worth of data.

When running a select statement it seemed to work for some tables (for example adroit.raw_data_2013_12_09) but not for tables that are created over 3 days ago (for example adroit.raw_data_2013_12_05)

Here is the error readout:

```
bigquery service returned an invalid reply in query operation: pagetoken missing
for table '123856490061:_2863529bd240bcbd666b3debc039d3c62827fd67.anon64863979ca
e70f1bf67661ed0fafb2a8c5bb36e1'.

please make sure you are using the latest version of the bq tool and try again.
if this problem persists, you may have encountered a bug in the bigquery client.
google engineers monitor and answer questions on stack overflow, with the tag
google-bigquery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery
please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well
as the following information:

========================================
== platform ==
  cpython:2.7.5:linux-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-5.0.8
== bq version ==
  v2.0.12
== command line ==
  ['/usr/local/bin/bq', 'query', '--max_rows=100000', '--format=csv', '-q', 'select count(*) as views, template_id, string_id, state_id, reel_1,reel_2,reel_3,reel_4,reel_5,reel_6,reel_7,reel_8,reel_9,reel_10 from adroit.raw_data_2013_12_03 where operation_type in (1,3)  and template_id in (2659,2660,2661) group by template_id, string_id,  state_id, reel_1,reel_2,reel_3,reel_4,reel_5,reel_6,reel_7,reel_8,reel_9,reel_10']
== utc timestamp ==
  2013-12-10 23:15:43
== error trace ==
  file "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bq.py", line 652, in runsafely
    return_value = self.runwithargs(*args, **kwds)
  file "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bq.py", line 932, in runwithargs
    max_rows=self.max_rows)
  file "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bq.py", line 383, in _printtable
    fields, rows = client.readschemaandrows(table_dict, **extra_args)
  file "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 668, in readschemaandrows
    self.readtablerows(table_dict, max_rows))
  file "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 649, in readtablerows
    apiclienthelper.tablereference.create(**table_dict),))
========================================


unexpected exception in query operation: pagetoken missing for table '1238564900
61:_2863529bd240bcbd666b3debc039d3c62827fd67.anon64863979cae70f1bf67661ed0fafb2a
8c5bb36e1'
```

---

So I tried easy_install update and the script says that my bq client is up to date.   I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting this error.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using an old version of bq. The latest version is 2.0.17.

```
$ bq version
This is BigQuery CLI v2.0.17
```

When you ran easy_install, did you use the `--upgrade` flag? If not, it doesn't actually update the version that you're using.

You can see the latest version at the download page [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/downloads/list).

Comment: That totally did the trick.   Forgot the --upgrade flag.  Thanks!